# Got error Input tensor must be at least 2D: [] [Op:BiasAddGrad] while implement custom loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

In my project, I have to customize the loss function which is the hungarian loss function.

```
def hungarian_algorithm_with_None(y_true, y_pred):
    from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
    BATCH_SIZE = 32

    final_cost = []

    for batch in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        y_true_ = y_true[batch,:]
        y_pred_ = y_pred[batch,:]
        store_element = np.ones(shape=(20,20))

        y_true_ = tf.cast(y_true_,dtype=tf.double)
        y_pred_ = tf.cast(y_pred_,dtype=tf.double)
        for i in range(y_true_.shape[0]):
            for j in range(y_pred_.shape[0]):     
                if not np.isnan(y_true_[i]) and not np.isnan(y_pred_[j]):
                    element = tf.square(y_true_[i] - y_pred_[j])            
                    store_element[i,j] = element
                    # store_element_None.append(element)

        cost = store_element # cost here is the values inside the table

        row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost)
        chosen_elements = set(zip(row_ind.tolist(), col_ind.tolist()))

        for sample in range(cost.shape[0]):
            for sirna in range(cost.shape[1]):
                if cost[sample, sirna] == 1:
                    cost[sample, sirna] = np.nan
                  
        cost = np.nanmin(cost,axis=1)
       
        cost = tf.cast(cost,dtype=tf.float32)
       
        final_cost.append(cost)

    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.experimental.numpy.nanmean(tf.reshape(final_cost,shape=(BATCH_SIZE,20)),axis=-1))

def hungarian_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cost = tf.py_function(func=hungarian_algorithm_with_None, inp=[y_true,y_pred], Tout=tf.float32,)
    cost_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(cost)
    # print(cost_tensor)
    return cost
```

When I test it with sample inputs and outputs

```
test_y_pred = tf.random.uniform(shape=(32,20,))
test_y_true = tf.random.uniform(shape=(32,20,))
```

It works fine and return this result

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.0017042245>
```

However, when I use it for training, it got errors at the line

```
grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, test_model.trainable_weights)
```

Here is the full customize training loop

```
x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
y = np.random.random((1000, 10))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))

loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
mae_metric = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="mae")
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-2)
for epoch in range(10):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))


    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset.batch(32)):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

            logits = test_model(x_batch_train, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch

            loss_value = hungarian_loss(y_batch_train, logits)
            # loss_value = custom_mse(y_batch_train, logits)
            
        tf.print(loss_value.shape)
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, test_model.trainable_weights) **--> error is here**

        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, test_model.trainable_weights))

        loss_tracker.update_state(loss_value)
        mae_metric.update_state(y_batch_train, logits)


        if step % 32 == 0:
            print(
                "Training loss (for one batch) at step %d: %.4f"
                % (step, float(loss_value))
            )
```

I cannot understand what cause that error. As you may see, I commented the line
"custom_mse(y_batch_train, logits)" . The shape output of this function is the same with the function hungarian_loss but it works with the training loop above. Here is the code for custom_mse

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true,dtype=tf.float32)
    y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred,dtype=tf.float32)
    # calculating squared difference between target and predicted values 
    loss = K.square(y_pred - y_true)  # (batch_size, 2)
    loss = tf.experimental.numpy.nanmean(loss,axis=-1)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

Answer (score 1):

For who is looking to the answer. I solved it by removing

```
def hungarian_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    cost = tf.py_function(func=hungarian_algorithm_with_None, inp=[y_true,y_pred], Tout=tf.float32,)
    cost_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(cost)
    # print(cost_tensor)
    return cost
```

The reason why I got this error is because when it calculates the backpropagation, the function tf.py_function doesn't call the function

```
def hungarian_algorithm_with_None(y_true, y_pred):
```

that's why it requires at least 2D tensor.

Additionally, never use numpy when customize the loss function, it will make the variables disconnect from the tensorflow graph, so the backpropagation cannot be calculated.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LLPyRAeDqmJ2swhLcHwSnNMtxJBBzzJc?usp=sharing